# Is there a { |x| x } shorthand in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I often use `.group_by{ |x| x }` and `.find{ |x| x }`

The latter is to find the first item in an array which is true.
Currently I'm just using `.compact.first` but I feel like there must be an elegant way to use find here, like `find(&:to_bool)` or `.find(true)` that I'm missing.
Using `.find(&:nil?)` works but is the opposite of what I want, and I couldn't find a method that was the opposite of #find or #detect, or a method like #true?

So is there a more elegant way to write `.find{ |x| x }`? If not, I'll stick with `.compact.first`
(I know compact won't remove `false` but that's not a problem for me, also please avoid rails methods for this)

Edit: For my exact case it is used on arrays of only strings and nils e.g.
`[nil, "x", nil, nil, nil, nil, "y", nil, nil, nil, nil]` => `"x"`

Comment: I'm really not sure what kind of shorthand you could be after. `{|x| x}` isn't short enough? After a point, trying to make code shorter is counter productive. I would always use the longer option here, `.compact.first`.

Comment: I think you're right, it's just ruby usually has a pretty way to handle things like this and I thought I overlooked one.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but I think `(&:dup)` works for mutable objects.  For example: `%w[a b a d b].group_by(&:dup)
 => {"a"=>["a", "a"], "b"=>["b", "b"], "d"=>["d"]}`.  I read where something is planned for Ruby that will do this properly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Duping each element might be a bit expensive.

Comment: For me, cost is no object.  Not recommending, just saying.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ahh that would be a cool hack if not for: `TypeError: can't dup NilClass`

Comment: What values your enumerable object does contain.. can you tell me?

Comment: Nil is not mutable.  Nor are Fixnums, Symbols, true, false and a few others.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit strings and nils, no empty strings and no other objects

Comment: Can you mention it on the post, I have a solution for the specific case..?

Comment: Use then only - `array.grep(String).first`. or `.compact.first`.

Comment: I reckon `array.find{ |x| x.is_a? String }` is better there, grep is very slow usually. I will go through these answers and compare their speeds because it's interesting to see which is fastest... but really I just want the shortest.

Comment: There's always `ident = lambda { |x| x }` and `group_by(&ident)` but that's a bit pointless unless, perhaps, you have a big chain of method calls and already have the logic chopped up into lambdas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not care about what is returned you can sometimes use the `hash` method.

Thw feature you are asking for is not available in Ruby yet, however. it is present in the Ruby road-map:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373

Expected to be implemented before 2035-12-25, can you wait?

That being said, how much typing is `group_by{|x|x}` ?

Edit:

As Stefan pointed out, my answer is now longer valid for Ruby 2.2 and above since the introduction of `Object#itself`.

Comment: Excellent news. I'll be counting down the days, exactly 8000 days left.

Comment: The first sentence is very important as `nil.hash` & `false.hash` return numeric values. This makes the original use case in the question (`detect`) not possible (i.e. `array.detect(&:hash) != array.compact.first`). But nice finding on the open issue!

Comment: Yea, `compact.first` is certainly better than `.find{ |x| x }` anyway - this feature would still be welcome even if it were only useful for `.group_by`

Comment: It's available in Ruby 2.2: [`Object#itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself)

Answer (score 2):

There’s not.

If [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) worked without a block you could do:

```
array.detect(&:tap)
```

But it doesn’t. Either way, I think **what you have is extremely concise, idiomatic**, and happens to be the same number of characters as the non-working above alternative, and thus you should stick with that:

```
array.compact.first
```

You could monkey-patch your way to getting a shorter version, but then it becomes unclear to anyone otherwise familiar with Ruby, which probably isn’t worth the minor “savings”.

As a curiosity, if you happened to want `array.detect { |x| !x }` (the opposite) you could do:

```
array.detect(&:!)
```

This works because `!x` is actually shorthand for `x.!`. Of course this would only ever give you `nil` or `false`, which is probably not very useful.

Comment: `array.detect(&:tap)` gives `LocalJumpError: no block given`

Comment: Damn I thought you had cracked it, but unfortunately I get `tap': no block given (LocalJumpError)`

Comment: That’s what I get for writing up an answer without running it late at night. Oh well. My last comment in the answer still stands, though: `compact.first` *is* the same number of characters, and I don’t think you’ll get any shorter than that in core Ruby. You could monkey-patch, but then it’s less idiomatic and probably not worth it. I’ll delete this answer at some point in order to give comment-reading time.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall even if `.find(&:tap)` had worked, `.compact.first` is actually *twice* as fast which is very surprising to me. (I benchmarked `.find{ |x| x}` vs `.compact.first`). So yea I think `.compact.first` is still the best way unless someone can make a short elegant solution like yours.

Comment: @user21033168 Not actually that surprising since `compact` can be optimized for just that, is written in pure-C, and avoids the overhead of block creation and N block calls.

Comment: @user21033168 I’ve forgone deleting my answer to instead decisively say there is not currently a shorthand for what you want and you should stick with what you have `:)`.

Comment: Ok, `&true.method(:&)` was the closest we got (but that answer was removed) shame `&:tap` doesn't work. I'll stick with `.compact.first`

Comment: @user21033168 I have deleted it as, people were keep disliking that one as an *not elegant one*..

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. I personally have a utility library I include in all my projects which has something like

```
IDENTITIY = -> x { x }
```

Then you would have

```
.group_by(&IDENTITY)
```

There is also `Object#itself` that simply returns `self`:

```
.group_by(&:itself)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the tag is for `ruby` - with Rails (more specifically ActiveSupport) you are given a method `presence` which will work for anything that responds positively to `present?` (that would exclude blank strings, arrays, hashes, etc):

```
array.find(&:presence)
```

It's not quite equivalent to the preferred result, but it will work for most cases I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use group_by, map, select, sort_by, and other various hash methods. I discovered this useful little extension yesterday by fiddling around with another answer on a similar question:

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(n)
    if has_key? n
      self[n]
    else
      raise NoMethodError
    end
  end
end
```

For any hash created by ruby, or any data that has been jsonified by as_json, this addition allows me to write code which is a little shorter. Example:

```
# make yellow cells
yellow = red = false
tube_steps_status.group_by(&:step_ordinal).each do |type|
    group = type.last.select(&:completed).sort_by(&:completed)
    red = true if group.last.step_status == 'red' if group.any?
    yellow = true if group.map(&:step_status).include?('red')
end
tube_summary_status = 'yellow' if yellow unless red
```